# SQL Server 2016 - How to select data as a range if all other parameters are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, range

Input data:

```
| CustomerName | TelephoneNumber | AddressLine1             | AddressLine2             | AddressLine3             | PostCode            |
|--------------|-----------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|---------------------|
| Company A    | 02000000000     | Company A Address Line 1 | Company A Address Line 2 | Company A Address Line 3 | Company A Post Code |
| Company B    | 02000000001     | Company B Address Line 1 | Company B Address Line 2 | Company B Address Line 3 | Company B Post Code |
| Company A    | 02000000002     | Company A Address Line 1 | Company A Address Line 2 | Company A Address Line 3 | Company A Post Code |
| Company A    | 02000000003     | Company A Address Line 1 | Company A Address Line 2 | Company A Address Line 3 | Company A Post Code |
| Company C    | 02000000004     | Company C Address Line 1 | Company C Address Line 2 | Company C Address Line 3 | Company C Post Code |
| Company C    | 02000000005     | Company C Address Line 1 | Company C Address Line 2 | Company C Address Line 3 | Company C Post Code |
| Company C    | 02000000006     | Company C Address Line 1 | Company C Address Line 2 | Company C Address Line 3 | Company C Post Code |
| Company C    | 02000000007     | Company C Address Line 1 | Company C Address Line 2 | Company C Address Line 3 | Company C Post Code |
```

Expected result:

```
| CustomerName | TelephoneNumber           | AddressLine1             | AddressLine2             | AddressLine3             | PostCode            |
|--------------|---------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|---------------------|
| Company A    | 02000000000               | Company A Address Line 1 | Company A Address Line 2 | Company A Address Line 3 | Company A Post Code |
| Company B    | 02000000001               | Company B Address Line 1 | Company B Address Line 2 | Company B Address Line 3 | Company B Post Code |
| Company A    | 02000000002 - 02000000003 | Company A Address Line 1 | Company A Address Line 2 | Company A Address Line 3 | Company A Post Code |
| Company C    | 02000000004 - 02000000007 | Company C Address Line 1 | Company C Address Line 2 | Company C Address Line 3 | Company C Post Code |
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>CustomerName</th>
    <th>TelephoneNumber</th>
    <th>AddressLine1</th>
    <th>AddressLine2</th>
    <th>AddressLine3</th>
    <th>PostCode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company A</td>
    <td>02000000000</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company A Post Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company B</td>
    <td>02000000001</td>
    <td>Company B Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company B Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company B Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company B Post Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company A</td>
    <td>02000000002</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company A Post Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company A</td>
    <td>02000000003</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company A Post Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company C</td>
    <td>02000000004</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company C Post Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company C</td>
    <td>02000000005</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company C Post Code</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Company C</td>
    <td>02000000006</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company C Post Code</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Company C</td>
    <td>02000000007</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company C Post Code</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>

<h2>Query should return this</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>CustomerName</th>
    <th>TelephoneNumber</th>
    <th>AddressLine1</th>
    <th>AddressLine2</th>
    <th>AddressLine3</th>
    <th>PostCode</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company A</td>
    <td>02000000000</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company A Post Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company B</td>
    <td>02000000001</td>
    <td>Company B Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company B Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company B Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company B Post Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company A</td>
    <td>02000000002 - 02000000003</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company A Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company A Post Code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Company C</td>
    <td>02000000004 - 02000000007</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 1</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 2</td>
    <td>Company C Address Line 3</td>
    <td>Company C Post Code</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to build a query such given the top table of data, the second table is returned. If all the parameters match the (CustomerName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3 and PostCode) and the TelephoneNumbers are consecutive they can grouped as a range. If they are not consecutive they should be shown on separate rows. The data provided is only a sample as there are several thousand rows in the table hence the solution needs to be dynamic so it can cope with any number of combinations.

So far I have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT TelephoneNumber, CustomerName, AddressLine1, Addressline2, AddressLine3, PostCode  
       LAG (TelephoneNumber, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, AddressLine4, PostCode ORDER BY CLI) AS PreviousTelephoneNumber
FROM DataTable
ORDER BY TelephoneNumber
```

However this has only returned me the Telephone number for the previous entry with the same parameters (Customername, AddressLine1, etc.).

I am not sure how to go from here to looking like the second table. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can have range of telephone numbers?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to have multiple phone numbers at the same address. Sometimes thousands of numbers. So the numbers may start at 02000000000 and end at 02000001000. In this case the telephone number column should show 02000000000 - 02000001000 if other parameters are the same.

Comment: No i mean could they really be consecutive? are phone numbers stored as strings? I was thinking about `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Yes they can be consecutive. Phone numbers are stored as strings. Running SQL Sever 2016 so I don't think STRING_AGG is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like below by using  `row_number()` find consecutive and non-consecutive number then take the `min` and `max` for range

```
 with cte as
(
select 'Company A' as CustomerName, 0200 as TelephoneNumber, 'A' as AddressLine1
union all 
select 'Company B',0201,'B' union all
select 'Company A',0202,'A' union all
select 'Company A',0203,'A' union all
select 'Company A',0204,'A'
)
 , cte2 as (SELECT
    *,row_number() over(partition by CustomerName order by TelephoneNumber) rn,
    row_number()over(order by TelephoneNumber) rn1
FROM cte
) select CustomerName,case when min(TelephoneNumber)=max(TelephoneNumber) then
  cast(min(TelephoneNumber) as varchar(500))
  else concat( cast( min(TelephoneNumber) as varchar(500)),'-',
  cast (max(TelephoneNumber)as varchar(500))) end as TelephoneNumber,AddressLine1
 from cte2 group by CustomerName,AddressLine1,rn1-rn
```

as in your case AddressLine2,AddressLine3, AddressLine4, PostCode will also come into group by and selection i just make demo by using 3 columns so i have not considered those in my query

```
CustomerName    TelephoneNumber     AddressLine1
Company A        200                 A
Company A        202-204             A
Company B        201                 B
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the telephone numbers with no gaps, so just subtract a sequence from them to get a constant value.  The rest is aggregation:

```
select CustomerName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, PostCode,
       (case when count(*) = 1 then min(TelephoneNumber)
             else concat(min(TelephoneNumber), '-', max(TelephoneNumber))
        end) as telephone_numbers
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CustomerName order by TelephoneNumber) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by CustomerName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, PostCode,
         (convert(decimal(38, 0) TelephoneNumber) - seqnum)
```